# How to plot the first point of each vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 8 vectors in MATLAB with dimension 1x18 which I have calculated like this:

```
i = 19
for c = 1:i
    rpm_new(c) = c*250;
end

for c = 1:i-1
    lambda_avg(c) = mean(sw1.Lambda((sw1.RPM >=rpm_new(c)) & sw1.RPM < rpm_new(c+1)));
    lambda_avg2(c) = mean(sw2.Lambda((sw2.RPM >=rpm_new(c)) & sw2.RPM < rpm_new(c+1)));
    lambda_avg3(c) = mean(sw3.Lambda((sw3.RPM >=rpm_new(c)) & sw3.RPM < rpm_new(c+1)));
    lambda_avg4(c) = mean(sw4.Lambda((sw4.RPM >=rpm_new(c)) & sw4.RPM < rpm_new(c+1)));
    lambda_avg5(c) = mean(sw5.Lambda((sw5.RPM >=rpm_new(c)) & sw5.RPM < rpm_new(c+1)));
    lambda_avg6(c) = mean(sw6.Lambda((sw6.RPM >=rpm_new(c)) & sw6.RPM < rpm_new(c+1)));
    lambda_avg7(c) = mean(sw7.Lambda((sw7.RPM >=rpm_new(c)) & sw7.RPM < rpm_new(c+1)));
    lambda_avg8(c) = mean(sw8.Lambda((sw8.RPM >=rpm_new(c)) & sw8.RPM < rpm_new(c+1)));
end
```

Now, I want to be able to plot the first element of each vector at x-coordinate 1, so something

```
scatter(1,lambda_avg(1))
hold on
scatter(1,lambda_avg2(1))
...
```

I then want to plot the second element of each vector at x-coordinate 2, so something like

```
scatter(2,lambda_avg(2))
hold on
scatter(2,lambda_avg2(2))
...
```

Is it possible to do this in a smart way, and to do it in a single plot? Would it also be possible to connect each point in a vector together? Such that all the points from `lambda_avg`  is connected by a line and the same for `lambda_avg2`?

Comment: `plot(1:length(lambda_avg), lambda_avg)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a matrix to store your results instead of individual vectors.

A neater way is to also use a 2nd loop (this relies on you also using `sw.Lambda1, sw.Lambda2, ...` instead of `sw1.Lambda, sw2.Lambda, ...`, which is a [better option](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval)). You could use 8 individual lines to assign the rows of the matrix if you wanted though.

```
lambda_avg = zeros(8,i-1);
for r = 1:8
    swr = sw.(['Lambda' num2str(r)]); % sw.Lambda1, sw.Lambda2, ...
    for c = 1:i-1
        lambda_avg(r,c) = mean(swr.Lambda((swr.RPM >=rpm_new(c)) & swr.RPM < rpm_new(c+1))); 
    end       
end
```

Then it's much easier to plot things, using a single call and without needing `hold`.

```
plot( 1:8, lambda_avg, '.k' );
```

---

Note that you could probably vectorise this further to remove at least one of the two loops, but that's beyond the scope of this question really as it requires changes to your earlier code. Read more about MATLAB vectorisation in the docs [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I just realized that I asked a wrong question... I actually wanted to plot the entire vector at one x-coordinate. So the whole lambda_avg vector at x=1, whole lambda_avg2 at x=2 and so on. But I will create a new question for that.

Comment: @Carl You can do exactly the same but use `plot( 1:(i-1), lambda_avg.', '.k' )` instead, which transposes `lambda_avg` because `plot` treats each column as a line